# Putting multiple outdoor lights on one timer switch?

Tags: electrical

I have a light switch panel, which controls three lights (picture to follow). Two switches on the left each control one outdoor light. I would like to put those switches on a timer.

I don't think that panel has room for two timer switches, plus the third that controls an indoor light. Is it possible to merge the two outdoor lights and connect it to one timer? I don't really care if I can't control the two outdoor lights independently anymore, it's fine if they're always controlled together.

Is there anything I need to be aware of if I try merging the two when looking for compatible timers? Here's a picture of the setup:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does the same circuit breaker turn off both outside lights?  (Probably does, but if not it’s an issue to overcome when combining).

Comment: Is there a neutral (white) wire available in the box? How deep is the box and what circuits go into the box? You want to make sure there is enough volume in the box to meed code. We can help with this if you provide a clear picture of the inside of the box showing the wires feeding the 3 switches. Finally, what sort of lights do you have/plan to have on the two circuits? Some timers can't handle fluorescent ballasts. Some are rated for higher amperage (most likely you won't need this).

Comment: Can you put a bigger box, or another box, there?